# Does Azure cosmos DB support byte[] storage?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

What is the best way to store byte[] in Azure cosmos DB? 
Converting byte[] to base64 encoded string is adding 33% over head in space and processing cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Byte arrays will automatically be converted to Base64 representations of them when you use the SDKs.

You cannot store raw byte arrays because everything is ultimately converted to a string representation of itself in the form of a json document.

If those byte arrays are not bigger than 2MB, you can add them as attachments and point to them from the document.

You can read more about attachments here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/attachments

Comment: Remember there's a 2GB/account attachment limit. It's not very practical.

Comment: I never said it is. Even Microsoft says that you are supposed to use Azure blog storage for this type of use case. I’m just keeping the answer on the context of the question.

Comment: As of 2022 I am seeing cosmosdb store byte array properties as arrays, not base64 strings, by default.